# (Django) Code runs fine locally but seems to stop after second iteration in production

Tags: python, django, selenium

I am scraping a website for their data, using Selenium (Firefox). I've created a UI with some buttons, like "start scrape" and "stop scrape." When someone with access to the UI clicks either of these buttons, it makes a call to a Django Rest Framework API which starts or stops a scrape.

Locally, everything runs fine and there seem to be no problems. However, in production, the scrape always only gets to the 2nd item that is to be collected. Here is the code:

```
# api/views.py
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0, decode_responses='utf-8')

@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def scrape_website(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        session_key = request.session.session_key

        r.set('scrape-stop-%s' % (session_key), 'no')
        r.expire('scrape-stop-%s' % (session_key), 60000)

        data = request.POST
        location = data.get('location')
        company_type = data.get('company_type')
        limit = data.get('limit')

        scrape(session_key, location, company_type)

        return Response({'msg': 'scrape successfully started'})

# scrape.py
def scrape(session_key=None, location='united_states', agency_type='digital_marketing_agencies', limit=200):

    options = Options()
    options.headless = True

    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.path.join(base_dir, 'reports'))
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False);
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showAlertOnComplete", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
    profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk','application/zip,application/octet-stream,application/x-zip-compressed,multipart/x-zip,application/x-rar-compressed, application/octet-stream,application/msword,application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/rtf,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet,application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document,application/xls,application/msword,text/csv,application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12,text/plain,text/csv/xls/xlsb,application/csv,application/download,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation,application/octet-stream')

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile, options=options)

    print('Working...')

    driver.get(links[location][agency_type])

    def get_boxes(location, agency_type, limit, index=0):

        print('index: %s' % (index))
        
        boxes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'sc-AykKC') and contains(@class, 'sc-AykKD') and contains(@class,'hfxDgE')]")

        while index <= (len(boxes) - 1):
            box = boxes[index]
            index += 1
            link_element = box.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@href,'profile')]") # period for relative xpath searching
            url = link_element.get_attribute('href')

            if url not in to_crawl:
                to_crawl.append(url)
                print('Got box for %s.' % (url))

        if index == (len(boxes) - 1):
            try:
                print('getting next page')
                next_page_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'page')]")
                next_page_button.click()
                get_boxes(location, agency_type, limit, index)

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

        for url_to_crawl in to_crawl:
            parse_info(url_to_crawl)

    def parse_info(url):

        if r.get('scrape-stop-%s' % (session_key)) == 'yes':
            return  
            
        # these try/excepts are to determine
        # if the xpath exists
        # let me know if you find an alternative
        # to this ugly method of doing this

        driver.get(url)

        print('trying url %s' % (url))

        annual_revenue = None
        num_employees = None

        try:
            if driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]').text == "Annual Revenue":
                annual_revenue = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]').text
        except Exception as e:
            print('annual_revenue', e)

        try:
            if driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]').text == "Number of employees":
                num_employees = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[7]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]').text
        except Exception as e:
            print('num_employees', e)

        name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/div').text
        url = driver.current_url

        address_text_list = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[5]/div/div[3]/div[1]').text.split('\n')

        if len(address_text_list) == 2:
            address = "No Address"
            city_state = address_text_list[0]
            phone_number = address_text_list[1]

        elif len(address_text_list) == 3:
            address = address_text_list[0]
            city_state = address_text_list[1]
            phone_number = address_text_list[2]

        location = '%s, %s' % (address, city_state)

        try:
            uc = Company.objects.create(
                annual_revenue=annual_revenue,
                num_employees=num_employees,
                phone_number=phone_number,
                name=name,
                url=url,
                location=location,
                company_type=agency_type,
            )

            print('Saved %s' % (name))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            
    get_boxes(location, agency_type, limit)
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

How I know it stops: In production, I check `journalctl -xe` and the scrape only makes it to the second company. The `get_boxes` function, however, goes all the way through.

Answer (score 0):

gunicorn was timing out. set --timeout=600 and everything worked fine